# Why pm2 deleting process automatically?

Tags: node.js, pm2

I am running 3 process in pm2. But after 2-3 month my process are getting deleted from pm2 list. Its like we just installed pm2.
I want to know why this is happening and how to rectify it.

Answer (score 3):

Are you sure that the PM2 daemon is still alive when you're doing the `pm2 list` ? If you run out of memory, chance are that your OS kill the pm2 daemon and by the way killing your application since they are process child of pm2 daemon.

Comment: yes , it was alive. memory is also available. This happens with my all node applications on diff servers.

Comment: You should try using the latest pm2 version : `npm install -g pm2 && pm2 update`